# Can't run a wasm file in mac using wasmtime

Tags: webassembly, wasmtime

My go code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello Web Assembly!")
}
```

Then I build the wasm file using the following command

```
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm
```

I got main.wasm file. Then I installed **wasmtime** to run the wasm files. When I tried to run the wasm file with wasmtime, I'm getting the following error,

> Error: failed to run main module `main.wasm`

> Caused by:
> >0: failed to instantiate "main.wasm"
> >1: unknown import: `go::debug` has not been defined

**My Go version:** 1.20,
**My wasmtime version:** wasmtime-cli 9.0.4,
**OS:** Mac

This is just a simple example. Is there anything, I'm doing wrong? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compile to `wasi` instead of `wasm` if you wanna run this using wasmtime.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `js` as the `target os` in your build target but trying to run the `wasm` file in `wasi` runtime.

Change the value of `GOOS`

Use this

```
GOOS=wasip1 GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm
```

Insted of this

```
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm
```